# System.out.println() changes value of a variable in single threaded program

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have been working an a good size but single threaded java application. In it I have a function which loops through a matrix of about size[300][10]. I have done a lot of things above this code snippet and have 3 other matrices of similar sizes as local variables. I was having problems with the loop not going through the first value (table[0][0]) when I noticed that the code:

```
System.out.println("");
for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
             if(i == 0 && j == 0){System.out.println("looped through 0 0");}
             // a bunch of other stuff
        }
}
```

prints out:

```
looped through 0 0
```

but the code:

```
//System.out.println("");
for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
             if(i == 0 && j == 0){System.out.println("looped through 0 0");}
             // a bunch of other stuff
        }
}
```

does not print anything.

Why would this be? Have I run out of Java heap space? Have I overflowed? Is this a compiler error?

Comment: Whats `table.length` and `table[0].length`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. On my Java 9 the second snippet too prints `looped through 0 0` (using `int[][] table = new int[300][10];`).

Comment: Both blocks are identical, so the problem is somewhere else. `System.out.println("");` also cannot influence

Comment: What's on the line right before `System.out.println("");`?  Is the println being executed conditionally?  If so, then commenting it out would cause the next line (the for loop) to be executed conditionally.

Comment: the only reason why it couldn't print is if tables have length zero. Try adding before the nested loop: `System.out.println(table.length);System.out.println(table[0].length);` . What does it print out?

Comment: @tkausl table.length and table[0].length are 292 and 6 but table size is based on input.

Comment: @Ole V.V I can not reproduce outside of project either

Comment: @mrog previous line is WorkItem[][] table = root.toTable(); where workitem is a class i made and root is a custom tree class that has a function to transform it into a table and this is working as expected. Not a conditional

Comment: Thank you all for the help! Additionally if I change System.out.println(""); to be System.out.println("some words"); "some words" is not printed, and if it is changed to System.out.printf("\n");  "looped through 0 0" is not printed. furthermore the rest of the two loops execute as normal

Comment: Yet a possible explanation is if `System.out` is redirected somewhere. Onviously commenting the quoted line out would not cause this to happen, though.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your development environment?  Whatever's going on, it's happening outside the scope of the code snippet in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found what was wrong. Above the loop I had another loop and had left a printf statement in there. I am still not sure why this occurs but I was able to reproduce it in the following class.

```
public class TestJavaPrintfError {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.printf("    ");
        }
        String[][] table = new String[300][6];

        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
                if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                    System.out.println("looped through 0 0");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am on developing on eclipse neon. Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Is that a joke?

Just scroll the console to the rightmost, you will see the print.

You are using `System.out.printf("    ");` 100 times, it output alot of spaces and push your pritnt to the right.

Comment: On one hand yes. My bad on the answer. It does just tab it over a bunch. But it  was not the problem i was originally having. In the answer try changing it  from 100 to 10000 then the statement changes to just 0 0 and it is on the following line. Change it to 5000 and it will print 0 0  just tabbed over a bunch. In my original code I had it print just characters which disappeared. I'm still wondering   why does this happen? I'm assuming its just the way eclipse handles printf on too many characters